# Mock many httpClient calls in the same method

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test using Moq and xunit. In this test, I have to mock two httpClient calls.

I'm writing unit tests for a dotnetcore API.
In my API I have to make 2 HTTP calls to another API in order to get the information I want.
- in the first call, I get a jwt token from this API.
- in the second call, I made a GetAsync call using the token which I getter in the first call to get the information I need.

I don't know how to do to mock these two different calls.
In this code, I can mock only one httpClient call

```
 var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            handlerMock
               .Protected()
               // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
               .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                  "SendAsync",
                  ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                  ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
               )
               // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
               .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
               {
                   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                   Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getEnvelopeInformationsResponse), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
               })
               .Verifiable();
```

Do you know how can I do to get two different calls and get two different HttpResponseMessage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `It.IsAny` and use `It.Is` instead.

The `It.Is` method will allow you to specify a predicate to see whether the parameter matches.

In your example:

```
handlerMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.Path == "/myjwtpath"),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(...))
    .Verifiable();

handlerMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.Path == "/myotherpath"),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(...))
    .Verifiable();
```

This will allow you to define a mock that returns two different values depending upon the inputted `HttpRequestMethod.RequestUri.Path` property.